# HTML5 Canvas change color HEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have a question about my HTML5 canvas, how can I change the color of a shape using HEX?

I have been able to change the color and size of a text but I would like to do the same to a shape, in this case a circle. 
Right now you enter a text in a textbox and you can change color and size.

Also, I want to be able to click on the canvas to paint one circle, then change color and make another circle in a different color than the first one.

My code for the text jsfiddle.net/e43nfx1d/4/
My code for the circle jsfiddle.net/w8wsv7sr

It was pretty easy to do the changes on the text but now, with the circle, Im totally lost.

/Wilma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I realized your question, your problem is to changing the color of filled circle.

There isn't any big problem here; You can change it as the same way of changing the text color.

Just like this:

```
context.fillStyle = "#333";
// Or any other color format that css supports
```

Here's your working example: http://jsfiddle.net/76koy1x7/

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to change the color of the circle by writing in textbox, for example: in the textbox, if I write 000000 I want that circle to be black, and for example: the next circle, I want that one to be white so i write FFFFFF. I will then have one black and one white circle... Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @cannondale Mine is not that good ;) Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/76koy1x7/1/

Comment: That is amazing! :D Now i just want to be able to change the size by typing for example 15 for 15px

Comment: @cannondale Sorry dude, We're not here to code for you. If my answer helped you, please accept it as best answer and tell me if there was any other question ( not task! )

Comment: Ocf! It should probably be able to find something in my old code and the one that you made to find an answer to how to change the size of the circles, in my old code (the one with the text) i have: context.font = fontStyle + " " + fontWeight + " " + circleSize +"px " + textFont; do you think I can use some part of it?

Comment: @cannondale You should to get the width of your circle ( like 24 ) then half it and pass it to your `context.arc()`  function like this:
`context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, sizeInput.value / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)`
As you see, third argument is the radius of your circle

Comment: var circleSize = "50";
  
  formElement = document.getElementById("circleSize");
 formElement.addEventListener("change", circleSizeChanged, false);
 
 context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, sizeInput.value / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 
 function circleSizeChanged(e){
  var target = e.target;
  circleSize = target.value;
  drawScreen();
 }

Comment: @cannondale check this: http://jsfiddle.net/76koy1x7/3/. works properly. Change the value of second input by numbers ( like: 24, 70 )

Comment: Sorry mrReiha your answer helped a lot! Thank you very much!